# Set cleared used in Hibernate mapping does not clear

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an object that has a parameter like follows:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customObject", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<MyCustomObject> objectss = new HashSet<>();
```

MyCustomObject is also mapped to a table.

If I want to clear this set by using

```
this.objectss.clear()
```

I see that the set is empty and has been cleared. However, if I access that same same at a later point the set contains all of the previous objects.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Can you give me some insight into what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: add attribute `orphanRemoval = true` in your @OneToMany annotation. if your main object is attached to the session and you invoke this.objectss.clear() the objectss will also be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the association to be cleared you will have to set the `customObject` association all the `MyCustomObject` elements to `null`. Not sure, but maybe `orphanRemoval = true` does exactly that.